# PHP Jquery Ajax POST call, not work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

As the title says, i have try many times to get it working, but without success... the alert window show always the entire source of html part.
Where am i wrong? Please, help me.
Thanks.

PHP:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
$file = $_POST['fblink'];
$contents = file_get_contents($file);

echo $_POST['fblink'];
exit;
}

?>
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#invia").click(function(e) {
        if( !confirm('Are you sure?')) {
        return false;
        }
        var fbvideo = $("#videolink").val();

        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: fbvideo ,
        cache: false,
        //dataType: "html",
        success: function(test){

            alert(test);
        }
        });
    e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<div style="position:relative; margin-top:2000px;">
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<input id="videolink" type="text" name="fblink" style="width:500px;">
<br>
<input id="invia" type="submit" name="send" value="Get Link!">
</form>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: An example input string and output would be helpful.

Comment: `$_POST['send']` and `$_POST['fblink']` would not send to the server. your `data` property is only a string of a value. try to send a object. look at the doc of jquery.ajax

Comment: @Sysix can you make me an example? Thanks

Comment: `data: {send: 1, fblink: fbvideo},` instead of `data: fbvideo ,`

Comment: @Sysix Yesss! I have change it to `data: { send: '', fblink: fbvideo },` and now is workink fine!
If you give an answer, i can accept yours. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Problem is that you think, that your form fields are automatic send with ajax. But you must define each one into it.

Try this code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#invia").click(function(e) {
        if( !confirm('Are you sure?')) {
        return false;
        }
        var fbvideo = $("#videolink").val();

        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            send: 1,
            fblink: fbvideo
        },
        cache: false,
        //dataType: "html",
        success: function(test){

            alert(test);
        }
        });
    e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

Instead of define each input for itself, jQuery has the method `.serialize()`, with this method you can easily read all input of your form.
Look at the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

And maybe You use `.submit()` instead of click the submit button. Because the user have multiple ways the submit the form.

```
$("input#invia").closest('form').submit(function(e) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You must specify the url to where you're going to send the data.
It can be manual or you can get the action attribute of your form tag.

If you need some additional as the `send` value, that's not as input in the form you can add it to the serialized form values with `formSerializedValues += "&item" + value;'` where `formSerializedValues` is already defined previously as `formSerializedValues = <form>.serialize()` (`<form>` is your current form).

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#invia").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) {
        return false;
      }
      // Now you're getting the data in the form to send as object
      let fbvideo = $("#videolink").parent().serialize();
      // Better if you give it an id or a class to identify it
      let formAction = $("#videolink").parent().attr('action');
      // If you need any additional value that's not as input in the form
      // fbvideo += '&item' + value;

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: fbvideo ,
        cache: false,
        // dataType: "html",
        // url optional in this case
        // url: formAction,
        success: function(test){
          alert(test);
        }
      });
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="position:relative; margin-top:2000px;">
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
      <input id="videolink" type="text" name="fblink" style="width:500px;">
      <br>
      <input id="invia" type="submit" name="send" value="Get Link!">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: i want to execute ajax inside the same file, for this i have not set the URL

Comment: URL is not required, if you make call to current page.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/36304545/4167976